# Passing parameters between activities not working

Tags: java, android, gridview

Passing parameters works with 2 normal activities, but when I try to pass this from the **gridview** to another activity, the value returns `null`

First Activity

```
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            //This takes the position id of the image and change
            //it to match category id
            position = position + 1;
            String positionId = String.valueOf(position);

            System.out.println(positionId);

            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "position =" + positionId + "\nid =" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MenuItemActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("hello", "hello");
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        }
    });
```

My secondary activity (MenuItemActivity.java)

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuitem);


    try{
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String category = null;
        extras.getString("Category "+extras.getString("hello"));
        System.out.println("Category = "+category);
    } catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from here it looks like a master >> detail page. if so why are you calling

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

instead of a simple

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```

can you try this and tell me if this works.

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("hello");
```

Comment: I'm just curious, what happens if I use startActivityForResult?

Comment: i think it might also work. its just if someone else sees the code. it might be misleading. as it happened for Tedd Hopp.

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, you need to call [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to actually pass data back to the first activity.

Comment: I don't want to return the data back to first activity. I just want to send it to the 2nd activity but it's not working